# wget -k doesn't convert all links

Tags: wget, mirror

I am trying to mirror a complete website to another domain.

I am trying to use

```
wget -mk http://example.com
```

However the -k option leaves some URLs original while other are converted such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/templates/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/css/ie.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/css/ie6.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Or img tags:

```
<img src="http://example.com/templates/img/logo.jpg"
```

While a-tags are converted properly.

These are from index.html, and the output of wget states, that index.html got converted

```
Converting example.com/index.html... 30-12
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

This from the wget manpage, which probably explains what you're seeing:

> -k
>   --convert-links
>
> After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to
>   make them suitable for local viewing.  This affects not only the
>   visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to
>   external content, such as embedded images, links to style sheets,
>   hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.
>
> Each link will be changed in one of the two ways:
>
> - The links to files **that have been downloaded by Wget** will be
>     changed to refer to the file they point to as a relative link.
>
> Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif,
>   also downloaded, then the link in doc.html will be modified to point
>   to ../bar/img.gif. This kind of transformation works reliably for
>   arbitrary combinations of directories.
>
> - The links to files **that have not been downloaded by Wget** will be
>     changed to include host name and absolute path of the location they
>     point to.
>
> Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif
>   (or to ../bar/img.gif), then the link in doc.html will be modified to
>   point to http://hostname/bar/img.gif.

Without further details it's difficult to be more precise.

Comment: i also tried to use --page-requisites which should download all links but doesnt. commandline I used now  wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent http://example.com but still css, and imgs are not downloaded

Comment: @Jherek are your missing css files, etc., really on the same website? (Remembering, of course, that *example.net* is not the same as *www.example.net*.)

Comment: The man page has been updated to emphasise this: `Note that only at the end of the download can Wget know which links have been downloaded. Because of that, the work done by -k will be performed at the end of all the downloads.`, which solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that there is a robots.txt file on the server. The option `-e robots=off` would help in that case. (It did for me in a similar situation.)

Answer (score 1):

In case the mirrored site is protected by HTTP Auth, one needs to use command line options to provide username and password. Something like `--http-user=someone` and `--http-password=secret` seems to work. Specifying the credentials as part of the url, `https://someone:secret@somewhere/`, gives the unexpected situation where only some files get downloaded, while wget attempts to fetch other files without authenticating. I'm sure there is a pattern and a sound reason for it, but I did not bother investigating the differences between the accessible and inaccessible links.